# How to solve "Permission denied" in getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript

I'm in Chrome on Windows.

I would like to use the camera in my web app that with a domain, say **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**.

We have a dev environment called **[www.dev.example.com](http://www.dev.example.com)**

We run the following code to get the camera video :

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        video: {
            facingMode: 'environment',
            audio: !1
        }
    }).then(function(e) {
        console.log('The camera is working');
    })
```

In the our dev domain ([www.dev.example.com](http://www.dev.example.com)) this code is working properly. However, when we change the domain to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), the code is not working any more (the exact same code). We get the error :

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Permission denied
```

We tried using Chrome Dev Console. In fact, this code works on any domain (including Stack Overflow) except our domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

Is there something domain-related to check in order to make this code work ?

Comment: Did you already deny camera access once on your domain? You might need to delete that preference.

Comment: I'm assuming `www.example.com` is `https` and not `http`,  if so you might have accidently disallowed camera access for this domain in the past, if so go to settings in Chrome , and under the privacy & security section, check the camera access for you domain.

Comment: @Keith if it was http, `navigator.mediaDevices` wouldn't even be accessible, throwing a TypeError. But the subdomain would make a difference.

Comment: @DustInComp  Yeah, it's just worth a mention, as a lot of new API's require secure context, but couldn't remember what errors throw what & when, so just thought I would take that bit out of the equation..

Comment: @Keith indeed, both domains are in https. And you are right. The domain has blocked camera in Chrome Settings. I dind't think about this since it was not working niether in my mobile phone. The problem is that I didn't know that Chrome reflects these securities settings to all the devices you're connected to. As long as it's the same gmail account, the  same security settings apply. Which is not very intuitive. You may want to block camera in a laptop and not on a mobile and vice versa. Thank you very much !